# Display alert box and stop changing background color after first click

Tags: php, ajax

I have two buttons(login and logout). Once user clicks on the login button, logout button will enable by changing background color and then when user clicks on the logout button, login will enable which is working fine. I need to display an **alert box** saying "**You are not allowed to select login more than one time a day**" and also stop changing the background color when user click on the login button again on the same day.

Thanks in advance

Code:

```
<script>
function insertDateTime(obj, id)
{
$("[id^='"+obj.id+"']").css('background', '#D4B357').css('font-weight', 'bold').css('font-size', '15px').css('color', 'black');
$(obj).css('background', '#FFFFFF').css('font-weight', 'normal').css('font-size', '14px').css('color', 'grey');

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

var params = "id="+id;

xmlhttp.open("POST","login_date_insert.php",true);

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
/*    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");*/
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}        
xmlhttp.send(params);
}
</script>
```

**getuser.php**

```
$entry=$row['entry'];
?>
<table>
<tr>
   <td>
       <button id="btnSave" <?php if($entry=='0'){?> style=" background:#D4B357; font-weight:bold; font-size:15px; color:black;outline:0px;"<?php }?> onclick="insertDateTime(this,'<?php echo $q;?>');"> Login</button>
   </td>
   <td>
       <button id="btnSave" <?php if($entry=='1'){?> style=" background:#D4B357; font-weight:bold; font-size:15px;color:black;outline:0px;"<?php }?> onclick="insertDateTime(this,'<?php echo $q;?>');"> Logout</button>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Create javascript variable, set to true or false where needed, alert when it's false or true.. done..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to stop changing background color also when user clicks again on login button after clicking logout button only on same day. The next day login should work.

Comment: Well then you just need some exta coding, you will have to log all user logins and check if a user has logged in at the current day, if so, set javascript variable as I mentioned before..